# ds4drv problem with steam

Tags: 14.04, steam, input-devices

Any one using `ds4drv` to emulate a 360 controller with a dualshock 4 ?

I have installed it and can take input from the controller, change the led colour, use the trackpad as a mouse and emulator recognize an `xbox 360 controller`, so this all seems good, right ?

The problem comes when I try Steam games, there is just no input from the controller, none at all while `ds4drv` is running.

The driver says it is running, and I gave my user the permissions but nothing.

This is the command I use to start it via USB

```
ds4drv --hidraw --emulate-xpad
```

Out put of this is

```
[info][controller 1] Created devices /dev/input/js0 (joystick) /dev/input/event17 (evdev) 
[info][controller 1] Connected to USB Controller (1C:66:6D:44:A5:39 hidraw5)
[info][hidraw] Scanning for devices
[info][controller 1] Battery: Fully charged
```

Looks all good to me, all I can think is the kernel driver and ds4drv are conflicting, how can I disable the kernel driver for the ds4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my hands on `ds4drv` this weekend, got some problems with it too(though my problem is a bit harder as I'm trying to use DS4 with Dark Souls in Wine through Steam).

First, native driver can interfere with your config (it works perfectly with DS4 though, native Steam detects controller as DS4 and all seems good), so you may wants to just delete `/dev/input/jsX` of native driver (do not unload `hid_sony` module as `ds4drv --hidraw` seem to use it).

Second, `ds4drv` by default starts in some sort of limited profile (just led and trackpad probably), so you may want to play with `ds4drv` config file to enable profile switching button (PS button by default) and configure your other profiles.